# How to write logs to different files using different references in SLF4J over LOG4J?

Tags: java, log4j

I am trying to write logs to different files; if I use `logger1`, it should write to my debug file and if I use `logger2`, it should write to my report folder.

```
private static  final Logger logger1= LoggerFactory.getLogger("debugLog");
private static  final Logger logger2= LoggerFactory.getLogger("reportsLog");
```

My log4j properties file is below:

```
    log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, stdout,debugLog,reportsLog
    log4j.logger.debugLog=TRACE,debugLog
    log4j.logger.reportsLog=DEBUG,reportsLog

    log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%24F:%t:%L] - %m%n

    log4j.appender.debugLog=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
    log4j.appender.debugLog.Threshold=TRACE
    log4j.appender.debugLog.File=C:\\debug.log
    log4j.appender.debugLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.debugLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%24F:%t:%L] - %m%n

    log4j.appender.reportsLog=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
    log4j.appender.reportsLog.Threshold=DEBUG
    log4j.appender.reportsLog.File=C:\\reports.log
    log4j.appender.reportsLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.reportsLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%24F:%t:%L] - %m%n

    log4j.category.debugLogger=TRACE, debugLog
    log4j.additivity.debugLogger=false

    log4j.category.reportsLogger=DEBUG, reportsLog
    log4j.additivity.reportsLogger=false
```

Comment: You have the two loggers, and you have the log4j configuration. What is your actual question? Is something not working correctly?

Comment: my requirement is when i log1 reference it should write to a separate file and when i use log2 reference it should write to a separate file in both files i need all levels of messages should be written can u please help me with that